# Semidefiniteness of the Hessian and optimization

Tags: optimization

This question is for sure a duplicate, but different users seem to give different answers. The question is: suppose you find that the Hessian matrix for a function $f(\textbf{x})$ is semidefinite positive *on the whole domain*. Are all stationary points also minima?

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27157/if-a-matrix-is-negative-semidefinite-does-it-have-a-local-maximum) it seems like the answer is positive, while [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27157/if-a-matrix-is-negative-semidefinite-does-it-have-a-local-maximum) it seems like it is negative.

There is a nice figure in Chiang, *Fundamental Methods of Mathematical Economics* (I don't know whether I can post a scanned image of it) in which you can read something like this: 1) if the Hessian is everywhere positive semidefinite, the function is convex; 2) if the function is convex, a stationary point is a global minimum. Moreover: 1) if the Hessian is everywhere positive definite, the function is *strictly* convex; 2) if the function is *strictly* convex, a stationary point is a unique global minimum.

Is that always right for $C^2$ functions?

Comment: Both of your links point to the same question. But it does not apply in your case because that question is talking about the Hessian at a single stationary point, not the whole domain like you are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question, including your question as a special case: See
[Local optimality of a KKT point.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051179/local-optimality-of-a-kkt-point).

The answer to your question depends on what is the whole domain of $x$. I.e. if the domain is a non-convex set (defined by non-convex constraints), then, a stationary point can be everything but is not necessarily a local or global minimum.